# Trouble following simplification stage of implicit differentiation problem - basic question

Tags: implicit-differentiation

> Show that the equation of the tangent at the point $(x_1,y_1)$ to the curve with equation $x^2-2y^2-6y = 0$ is $xx_1-2yy_1-3(y+y_1)=0$

Alright I'm having a problem following an example from my textbook. I'll just show what I do follow and then where I get confused.

Okay so I know how to find the equation of the tangent from first getting the gradient by differentiation.

$x^2-2y^2-6y=0$

$\Rightarrow$  $2x-2(2y\frac{dy}{dx})-6\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{3+2y}$

The gradient of the tangent at the point $(x_1,y_1)$ is $\frac{x_1}{3+2y_1}$

The equation of the tangent is given by $y-y_1=\frac{x_1}{3+2y_1}(x-x_1)$ which can be written as:

$(y-y_1)(3+2y_1)=x_1(x-x_1)$

The textbook says that this simplifies down to

$xx_1-2yy_1-3(y+y_1)=x_1^2-2y_1^2-6y_1$

I know I'm doing something wrong cause when I expand $(y-y_1)(3+2y_1)=x_1(x-x_1)$ I don't get that.

I get:

$3y-3y_1+2yy_1-2y_1^2=xx_1-x_1^2$ and then rearranging that I get

$xx_1-2yy_1-3(y-y_1)=x_1^2-2y_1^2$

And that's completely different to my textbook's answer.

So if anyone can shed some light on how

$(y-y_1)(3+2y_1)=x_1(x-x_1)$ simplifies to $xx_1-2yy_1-3(y+y_1)=x_1^2-2y_1^2-6y_1$

then I would be extremely grateful.

P.S Sorry to ask such a basic question I'm quite new to learning this stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add $6y_1$ to both sides of the text's "simplified" equation, you get your equation. Yours is actually simpler. Your algebra is correct.